# Updating datagridview in Window application

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a table with 6 columns ID,A,B,C,D and E. ID is primary key. 
An third party application keep updating Column D and E and also 
adding new rows to the table.

I want to display this table to a datagridview control. I am trying to update it each after 5 sec. So far i have tried:

Table may have 3-100 records.

//dt is a DataTable with new data

//dtPos is DataTable currently bind to datagridview

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    dtPos.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = '" + r["ID"].ToString() + "'";
    if (dtPos.DefaultView.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dtPos.DefaultView.Table.Rows[0]["D"] = r["D"];
        dtPos.DefaultView.Table.Rows[0]["E"] = r["E"];
    }
    else
    {
        dtPos.Rows.Add(r);
    }
}
```

This did not seem to work as expected. any better idea?

Comment: Post more code , how you are updating grid every 5 sec as well is this table is in database and you are querying database at regular interval of 5 secs.

Answer (score 1):

hi i suggest you to do above your task in gridview itself so you can do it instantly insteed of doing it in table and then assigning it back to the datagridview.
dgv have add row  method so you can add row in dgv directly .

use like this when u need to add new row

```
dgv.Rows.Add(1,2,3,4,4,5);
```

and when u need to change the value of the cell then

```
dgv.rwos[roindex].cells[cellindex].value = xxx; //your new value;
```

this can help u ....

Comment: Well we do not need to assign it back to datagridview. It get changed because it is bind with that data. My code is more efficient than one you suggested.